# Showing next quiz string when answered correctly

Tags: java, swing

I am in the middle of creating a children's board game, that asks random maths questions and players move if they answer right. I have a main BoardGUI class that includes 2 panels. One for the board, and one for the questions.

I'm having trouble with the Question panel. I'm reading in questions from a text file and saving each question as an object within an array. The issue is I can answer one question correctly and it will refresh the question with a new one, however doesn't keep doing this.

I'll paste the QuestionGUI class, as I think this is the one with issues to do with generating the same question/answers from a random number.

```
 public class QuestionGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

      JLabel question;
      JButton btnAnswers[];
      Reader r1 = new Reader();
      Questions q1 = new Questions();
      Random rand = new Random();
      boolean answered;

      int random = rand.nextInt(r1.ArraySize());
      int random2 = rand.nextInt(r1.ArraySize());
      int length = q1.getArrayItem(random).getAnswers().length;


      public QuestionGUI() {
        questionInit(random);
      }

      public void questionInit(int randomNum) {
        this.random = randomNum;
        //gets the answers from the array obj
        String[] answers = q1.getArrayItem(random).getAnswers();
        //sets the question from question of array obj (same obj as answers I assumed, using random num)
        question = new JLabel("<html>" + (q1.getArrayItem(random).getQuestion()) + "</html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        question.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 100));
        add(question);
        btnAnswers = new JButton[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          btnAnswers[i] = new JButton(answers[i]);
          btnAnswers[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(280, 60));
          btnAnswers[i].addActionListener(this);
          add(btnAnswers[i]);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //sets the correct answers to question also using the random num
        String[] correctAnswers = q1.getArrayItem(random).getCorrectAnswers();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          if (e.getSource().equals(btnAnswers[i])) {
            String tmp1 = btnAnswers[i].getText();
            if (Arrays.asList(correctAnswers).contains(tmp1)) {
              System.out.println("Correct");
              removeAll();
              revalidate();
              answered = true;
              questionInit(random2);
              repaint();

            } else {
              answered = false;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      public boolean getAnswered() {
        return answered;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you only generate the random number used as the index once.

```
int random2 = rand.nextInt(r1.ArraySize());
.
.
.
questionInit(random2);
```

You need to regenerate a random number each time. You can write a helper method to do this, or just put the code in the argument:

```
questionInit(rand.nextInt(r1.ArraySize()));
```

This might require additional refactoring.

Comment: I think you could be right! I've been staring at it for too long not realising that. Fresh eyes are always good!